# Failed to proxy to nodejs/express socket io server with nextjs

Tags: express, next.js, socket.io, proxy

I'm trying to create a connection between my next/react client with my express/socket.io backend (it is not running as a nextjs custom server). When proxying regular http requests using rewrites in the next.config.js file, it works perfectly fine. However, when I try and connect to the server via websockets (using socket.io) it gives this error in the terminal:

```
Failed to proxy http://localhost:8000/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=websocket Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:705:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:518:23)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

Here is my app.js at `./backend/app.js`:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const cookies = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const connect = require("./models/database");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

// Connection to MongoDB database
connect();

// Defining middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookies());
app.use(cors());
app.use(require("./middleware/logger"));

// Defining api route
app.use("/v1", require("./api/v1"));

// Defining websocket entry point
io.on("connection", require("./api/socket.io-v1"));

// starting server
server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`[STATUS]: Server started at port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

Here is my next.config.js at `./frontend/next.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

module.exports = () => {
  const rewrites = () => {
    return [
      {
        source: "/v1/:path*",
        destination: "http://localhost:8000/v1/:path*",
      },
      {
        source: "/socket.io/:path*",
        destination: "http://localhost:8000/socket.io/:path*",
      },
    ];
  };

  return {
    rewrites,
  };
};
```

And lastly the `socket` instance is defined like this in one of the component files (but importantly outside of the component):

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000", { transports : ['websocket'] });
```

Can someone tell me how I would go about proxying the socket connection to the external express server as I've been able to easily proxy requests when simply using create-react-app so I'm sure it's a problem with next.js. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem.

```
http://localhost:8000/socket.io?EIO=4&transport
```

Same problem with curl:

```
curl "http://localhost:3010/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OHwXDb-"
```

But works only with forward slah:

```
curl "http://localhost:3010/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OHwXDb-"
```

Nextjs rewrites destination always lost slash. I removed :path*, and then working:

```
{
  source: '/socket.io',
  destination: `${process.env.NEST_API}/socket.io/`,
 }
```

Or you can use path

```
 {
      source: '/socket.io/events/:path*',
      destination: `${process.env.NEST_API}/socket.io/events/:path*`,
     }
```

Than will work with :path*.

Answer (score 0):

I would still like to see if anyone has an answer to this question but as it stands I've just directly changed the socket.io connection url to the exact address of the server:

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:8000", { transports : ['websocket'] });
```